# How do you register a Postgres container host on docker-compose up?

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose, ponyorm

I have an app (Flask/Pony ORM) container that must register the host for a postgres db container on start up.  How can I get the host's (postgres container) location?

On my local set up I have "localhost" but this does not work in the app container.

I tried "172.17.0.2" which was what the pg containers IP when I was **not** using docker-compose.

But both of these return an error.

Is there a way to specify a host location for a particular container in the docker-compose file?

Comment: Could you please share your `.yml` file and how you're setting up your database with PonyORM? I'm trying to use the name of the mysql container as the host in PonyORM setup but it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must link your two containers in your docker-compose file. Then you will be able to access to your database using the service name of the container.

Example

```
links:
  - postgres:postgres
```

Link your `docker-compose.yml` if you need more help.